# How to use multiple calendars with vue-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3

I'm using the Composition API the [Vuepic/vue-datepicker library](https://github.com/Vuepic/vue-datepicker) and I have the following issue. I created a datepicker with the following issues:

```
<Datepicker
  multi-calendars
  multi-calendars-solo
  class="flex-1"
  format="dd/MM/yyyy"
  v-model="rangeDate"
  :enable-time-picker="false"
  range
  auto-apply
  :partial-range="true"
  placeholder="add a range of dates"
  text-input
  :preset-ranges="presetRanges"
  @update:model-value="getOverviewhse()"
  :min-date="new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 5))"
  :max-date="new Date()"
  prevent-min-max-navigation
>
  <template #yearly="{ label, range, presetDateRange }">
    <span @click="presetDateRange(range)">{{ label }}</span>
  </template>
</Datepicker>
```

The problem is that I want today's date to always be on the right and the previous month on the left to avoid what appears in the image that the right calendar is disabled. How can I do it?

[image: The image]

In other words, for example, in the month of May, it should be on the left, and the month of June should be on the right.

Comment: How do I get the pre-set ranges down the lefthand side like you have in image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue3Datepicker always sets up current month on the left.
I had similar issue with displaying three months at one time and I wanted to have current month in the middle, when (by default) it was always displayed on the left.

**I achieved the current month in the middle by**:

1. Adding needed props

```
<VueDatePicker id="inventory-date" v-model="inventoryForm.date" 
:enable-time-picker="false" 
:multi-calendars="{ count: 3 }"
:start-date="startDate" focus-start-date>
</VueDatePicker>
```

Crucial is this part `:start-date="startDate" focus-start-date` 
2. Returning wanted value of `startDate`

```
export default {
    name: "Foo",
    components: {
        VueDatePicker
    },
    setup() {
        const today = new Date();
        const prevMonth = new Date();
        prevMonth.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1);

        return {
            startDate: prevMonth
        }
    }
}
```

### In your case I would suggest to not make two separates calendars, but one with two displayed months and moved start date.

```
    <Datepicker
      class="flex-1"
      format="dd/MM/yyyy"
      v-model="rangeDate"
      :enable-time-picker="false"
      range
      auto-apply
      :partial-range="true"
      placeholder="add a range of dates"
      text-input
      :preset-ranges="presetRanges"
      @update:model-value="getOverviewhse()"
      :min-date="new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 5))"
      :max-date="new Date()"
      prevent-min-max-navigation
      :multi-calendars="{ count: 2 }"
      :start-date="startDate"
      hide-offset-dates
    >
    </Datepicker>
```

I've deleted

```
multi-calendars
multi-calendars-solo
```

and I added

```
  :multi-calendars="{ count: 2 }"
  :start-date="startDate"
  hide-offset-dates
```

Docs: 
https://vue3datepicker.com/props/modes/#multi-calendars
 
https://vue3datepicker.com/props/calendar-configuration/#start-date 
https://vue3datepicker.com/props/calendar-configuration/#hide-offset-dates